# multioutput regression by xgboost

Tags: machine-learning, random-forest, xgboost

Is it possible to train a model by [xgboost](/questions/tagged/xgboost) that has multiple continuous outputs (multi-regression)?
What would be the objective of training such a model?

Thanks in advance for any suggestions

Comment: If the output is more than one value, then you need a sequence model like RNN (GRU, LSTM etc.). [Keras](https://keras.io/) can help you quickly prototype such models.

Comment: I'm aware of RNN. I'm was wondering if such thing was also possible in Xgboost since I already know that boosting trees perform well for my problem space. I should also note that my output vecor size can be fixed.

Comment: If the relations between the outputs are known, you should be able to implement an objective function taking advantage of that. It has been done for [random forest with linear relation](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/MultivariateRandomForest/MultivariateRandomForest.pdf). And the XGBoost author thinks [it is doable](https://github.com/dmlc/xgboost/issues/680).

Comment: @uyaseen this is not true, that is only when there is a variable number of outputs (and that is not even neccesarily true). You can have multiple outputs and calculate a summed loss over them

Answer (score 67):

My suggestion is to use [sklearn.multioutput.MultiOutputRegressor](http://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.multioutput.MultiOutputRegressor.html) as a wrapper of `xgb.XGBRegressor`. `MultiOutputRegressor` trains one regressor per target and only requires that the regressor implements `fit` and `predict`, which [xgboost](/questions/tagged/xgboost) happens to support.

```py
# get some noised linear data
X = np.random.random((1000, 10))
a = np.random.random((10, 3))
y = np.dot(X, a) + np.random.normal(0, 1e-3, (1000, 3))

# fitting
multioutputregressor = MultiOutputRegressor(xgb.XGBRegressor(objective='reg:linear')).fit(X, y)

# predicting
print(np.mean((multioutputregressor.predict(X) - y)**2, axis=0))  # 0.004, 0.003, 0.005
```

This is probably the easiest way to regress multi-dimension targets using [xgboost](/questions/tagged/xgboost) as you would not need to change any other part of your code (if you were using the [sklearn](/questions/tagged/sklearn) API originally).

However, this method does not leverage any possible relation between targets. But you can try to design a [customized objective](https://github.com/dmlc/xgboost/blob/master/demo/guide-python/custom_objective.py) function to achieve that.

Comment: What if some x's have 1 target and some 50?

Comment: @Eran what do you mean by 'some 50'?

Comment: I mean that the number of outputs for each sample is not fixed.

Comment: Can you give me an example? A regression problem should have fixed shape of input and output. Otherwise it's not one single problem and should be treated separately.

Comment: For example you are asked to predict location/s (say in an array of locations) of different particles, and it is sometimes valid that some particle have more than one location (say up to 6 valid locations).

Comment: Perhaps you might need to a technique such as "feature hashing" (the hashing trick)

Comment: This isn't a model with two outputs; It's a wrapper around two models.

Comment: MultiOutputRegressor doesn't update validation dataset

Comment: To whom it might be relevant: In the paper "Do we really need deep learning for time series forecasting?" the authors used sklearn's MultiOutputRegressor to perform multi-step time series forecasting (e.g. predicting the next 24 hours of values for some variable). The authors claim to beat many neural network based approaches with this approach.  [Paper](https://arxiv.org/abs/2101.02118) & [code](https://github.com/Daniela-Shereen/GBRT-for-TSF)

Answer (score 11):

Multiple output regression is now available in the nightly build of XGBoost, and will be included in XGBoost 1.6.0.

See https://github.com/dmlc/xgboost/blob/master/demo/guide-python/multioutput_regression.py for an example.

Comment:  This is great news! Thank you for sharing!

Comment: Any difference when I fit each model for each y target independently?

Comment: Apparently, this library implementation still builds separate models for each output rather than a shared one: https://github.com/dmlc/xgboost/blob/master/doc/tutorials/multioutput.rst

Answer (score 6):

It generates warnings:

> `reg:linear is now deprecated in favor of reg:squarederror`

, so I updated an answer based on @ComeOnGetMe's

```py
import numpy as np 
import pandas as pd 
import xgboost as xgb
from sklearn.multioutput import MultiOutputRegressor

# get some noised linear data
X = np.random.random((1000, 10))
a = np.random.random((10, 3))
y = np.dot(X, a) + np.random.normal(0, 1e-3, (1000, 3))

# fitting
multioutputregressor = MultiOutputRegressor(xgb.XGBRegressor(objective='reg:squarederror')).fit(X, y)

# predicting
print(np.mean((multioutputregressor.predict(X) - y)**2, axis=0))
```

Out:

```
[2.00592697e-05 1.50084441e-05 2.01412247e-05]
```

Answer (score 3):

I would place a comment but I lack the reputation. In addition to @Jesse Anderson, to install the most recent version, select the top link from here:
https://s3-us-west-2.amazonaws.com/xgboost-nightly-builds/list.html?prefix=master/

Make sure to select the one for your operating system.

Use pip install to install the wheel. I.e. for macOS:

`pip install https://s3-us-west-2.amazonaws.com/xgboost-nightly-builds/master/xgboost-1.6.0.dev0%2B4d81c741e91c7660648f02d77b61ede33cef8c8d-py3-none-macosx_10_15_x86_64.macosx_11_0_x86_64.macosx_12_0_x86_64.whl`

Answer (score 2):

The [2.0.0 xgboost release](https://github.com/dmlc/xgboost/releases/tag/v2.0.0) supports multi-target trees with vector-leaf outputs.
Meaning, xgboost can now build multi-output trees where the size of leaf equals the number of targets.  The tree method `hist` must be used.

Specify the `multi_strategy = "multi_output_tree"` training parameter to build a multi-output tree:

```
clf = xgb.XGBClassifier(tree_method="hist", multi_strategy="multi_output_tree")
```

A regression example based on @ComeAndGetMe's answer:

```
import numpy as np 
import pandas as pd 
import xgboost as xgb

print('xgb version:', xgb.__version__)

# get some noised linear data
X = np.random.random((1000, 10))
a = np.random.random((10, 3))
y = np.dot(X, a) + np.random.normal(0, 1e-3, (1000, 3))

# fitting
multioutputregressor = xgb.XGBRegressor(objective      = "reg:squarederror",
                                        tree_method    = "hist", 
                                        multi_strategy = "multi_output_tree")
multioutputregressor.fit(X, y)

# predicting on the training data
print('mse:', np.mean((multioutputregressor.predict(X) - y)**2, axis=0))
```

Output:

```
xgb version: 2.0.0
mse: [9.43447858e-05 8.78643942e-05 9.99183540e-05]
```

Setting `multi_strategy="one_output_per_tree"`, the default, will build one model per-target.  In general, I would expect this option to give better results.

See also the xgboost [tutorial for multi-output regression](https://xgboost.readthedocs.io/en/stable/tutorials/multioutput.html).

As of this writing, xgboost support for multiple outputs is considered experimental and only the python version is tested.

Answer (score 1):

Based on the above discussion, I have extended the univariate [XGBoostLSS](https://github.com/StatMixedML/XGBoostLSS) to a multivariate framework called [Multi-Target XGBoostLSS Regression](https://arxiv.org/abs/2210.06831) that models multiple targets and their dependencies in a probabilistic regression setting. Code follows soon.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

You can use Linear regression, random forest regressors, and some other related algorithms in scikit-learn to produce multi-output regression. Not sure about XGboost. The boosting regressor in Scikit does not allow multiple outputs. For people who asked, when it may be necessary one example would be to forecast multi-steps of time-series a head.