# invalid shape as output when i fit the model with xgboost

Tags: python

I am trying to predict data on XGBRegressor but when i fit the model it give me value error of invalid shape.

from xgboost import XGBRegressor

my_model = XGBRegressor()
my_model.fit(X_train,y_train)

ValueError: Invalid shape: (4074, 5) for label

Comment: amd what is X shape?

Comment: here I am using the same data and same model https://www.kaggle.com/alexisbcook/xgboost

Answer (score 1):

If you want to have multiple outputs then use MultiOutputRegressor, as described [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39540123/muti-output-regression-in-xgboost), otherwise y_train must have only 1 dimension.

Comment: I am doing kaggle exercise https://www.kaggle.com/alexisbcook/xgboost here it doesn't seem using y_train as 1 dimension

Comment: yes they are `y = data.Price`, y is just a number

Comment: I use the same target as y  = data.Price but giving me error don't know as i checked several time giving me headach