# Error message: ValueError: Invalid shape: (84, 2) for label

Tags: machine-learning, regression, xgboost

I got this error message:

```
ValueError: Invalid shape: (84, 2) for label
```

after I was attempting to predict two outputs by using XGBoostRegressor with the following code:

```
dataset = pd.read_csv (r"D:\Downloads (D)00000000\Zeyad2\zeyad2.csv")
df=pd.DataFrame(dataset)
x = df.iloc[:,0:6]
y = df.iloc[:, [6,7]]
from sklearn.model_selection import train_test_split
x_train, x_test, y_train, y_test = train_test_split(x, y, test_size=0.2, random_state=0)
xgbr = XGBRegressor(verbosity=None, learning_rate=0.04,  n_estimators=110, max_depth=3,subsample=0.5, gamma=10,
                    min_child_weight=None, colsample_bylevel=None, max_delta_step=None, colsample_bynode=None)
xgbr.fit(x_train, y_train)
```

But then, I got these error messages and warnings:

```
Bad key "text.kerning_factor" on line 4 in
D:\anacond\envs\first\lib\site-packages\matplotlib\mpl-data\stylelib\_classic_test_patch.mplstyle.
You probably need to get an updated matplotlibrc file from
https://github.com/matplotlib/matplotlib/blob/v3.1.3/matplotlibrc.template
or from the matplotlib source distribution
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "D:/pythonfirst/Student.py", line 23, in <module>
    xgbr.fit(x_train, y_train)
  File "D:\anacond\envs\first\lib\site-packages\xgboost\core.py", line 506, in inner_f
    return f(**kwargs)
  File "D:\anacond\envs\first\lib\site-packages\xgboost\sklearn.py", line 776, in fit
    enable_categorical=self.enable_categorical,
  File "D:\anacond\envs\first\lib\site-packages\xgboost\sklearn.py", line 295, in _wrap_evaluation_matrices
    enable_categorical=enable_categorical,
  File "D:\anacond\envs\first\lib\site-packages\xgboost\sklearn.py", line 775, in <lambda>
    create_dmatrix=lambda **kwargs: DMatrix(nthread=self.n_jobs, **kwargs),
  File "D:\anacond\envs\first\lib\site-packages\xgboost\core.py", line 506, in inner_f
    return f(**kwargs)
  File "D:\anacond\envs\first\lib\site-packages\xgboost\core.py", line 635, in __init__
    feature_weights=feature_weights,
  File "D:\anacond\envs\first\lib\site-packages\xgboost\core.py", line 506, in inner_f
    return f(**kwargs)
  File "D:\anacond\envs\first\lib\site-packages\xgboost\core.py", line 694, in set_info
    self.set_label(label)
  File "D:\anacond\envs\first\lib\site-packages\xgboost\core.py", line 825, in set_label
    dispatch_meta_backend(self, label, 'label', 'float')
  File "D:\anacond\envs\first\lib\site-packages\xgboost\data.py", line 897, in dispatch_meta_backend
    _validate_meta_shape(data, name)
  File "D:\anacond\envs\first\lib\site-packages\xgboost\data.py", line 829, in _validate_meta_shape
    raise ValueError(f"Invalid shape: {data.shape} for {name}")
ValueError: Invalid shape: (84, 2) for label`
```

Someone told me that maybe the problem because of the python version or xgboost verstion, but I checked, they are met.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [multioutput regression by xgboost](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39540123/multioutput-regression-by-xgboost)